# Adjust view's position on other view's visibility in Relative Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I do this only with xml :

1. View-A in a Relative Layout is aligned to some View-B when its
   visible.
2. View-A in a Relative Layout is aligned to some View-C when
   View -B is gone ??

Consider C above B and B above A  :

[image]

Comment: please be clear or else post ur code

Comment: please post your code \

Comment: I updated my answer for your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not directly do that in xml, but depending of your needs, you can use [layout_alignWithParentIfMissing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing).

For exemple if View-A is left align to View-B and View-B visibility is Gone, View-A will be left align to their Relative Layout parent.

See the next example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/viewB"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If viewB is visible, viewB will be at the right of RelativeLayout, and viewA will be at its left. If viewB is gone, viewA will be at the right of RelativeLayout.

Without this line:

```
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" />
```

viewA would be displayed at the RelativeLayout left when viewB is gone...

For your example, you just need to replace layout_toLeftOf attribute by layout_above.

Otherwise you need to change View-A or View-B alignment programmatically in your activity (or fragment, or anywhere...)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the order is A to the left of B (or C if B is not visible), but same logic applies if you reverse the order. With the assumption you can do as follows:

- Make B align to right of A
- Make A align to left of C

With this, when B is visible, it will be to the right of A, which means A is aligned to the left of both B and C. When B is gone, the 1st condition is gone, so A is only aligned to left of C.